# Getting title attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

assume that I have this list:

```
<ul id="carousel"> 
    <li><a title="hey"><img src="image.png"/></a></li>  
</div>
```

And now my jQuery script:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#carousel a").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('title');
    alert(url);

    });
});
```

This doesn't work, it works for other attributes such as "alt", "rel" etc. I will be greatful for any assistance.

Comment: Is that extra quote intentional?

Comment: Attributes, not tags. `<title>` is a tag, and it has a very different meaning to the title attribute.

Comment: I hope that the `</div>` is a `</ul>` in your real markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Works for me](http://jsbin.com/uzofu) in Safari 4 on Mac OS X. What browser are you using? Does the example I linked to fail for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is perfect (because I did try it and it works) , if you using IE8 try to cleare the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will not work in Firefox because of your invalid markup (as seen in Brian Campbell's link). IE8 seems to work fine following the same link. It would seem that IE8 does not care about closing the `<ul>`.